# Load JSON File to ListBox and TextBox C#

Tags: c#, json, listbox

I'm working on a Windows Form Application. Textbox index can be saved and shown as  in ListBox with this code:

```
private List<FunctionData> funcParamList = new List<FunctionData>();
  ...
private void addFuncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FunctionData funcParams = new FunctionData();
        funcParams.blabla1name = blabla1.Text;
        funcParams.blabla2name = blabla2.Text;
        ...
        if (funcParams.isValid())
        {
            funcParamList.Add(funcParams);
            functionListBox.Items.Add(functionNameBox.Text);
        }
```

Also I collect objects to TextBox again to edit (by clicking ListBox item) with the following code :

```
  private void getParams(FunctionData data)
    {
        blabla1.Text = data.blabla1name;
        blabla2.Text = data.blabla2name;
        functionNameBox.Text = data.functionName;
        return;
    }

    private void functionListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (functionListBox.SelectedItem == null) { return; }
        foreach (var obj in funcParamList)
        {
            if (obj.functionName == functionListBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                getParams(obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

And save them to file as JSON with:

```
private void saveFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileName = fileNameBox.Text;
        string jsonFunc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(funcParamList);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"<blablapath>\" + fileName + ".txt", jsonFunc);
    }
```

There's 'functionName' object in JSON file that I can use it for showing on ListBox.

My question is: How can I load this file buy Native Load/Open File Dialog and show the objects in ListBox and can  edit them again?

And here how I've tried to make it with the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
private void loadFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog loadFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        ...

        if (loadFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string jsonFileName = loadFileDialog.FileName;
            string jsonFile = File.ReadAllText(jsonFileName);

            dynamic loadedFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonFile);

            //if (functionListBox.SelectedItem == null) { return; }
            foreach (var obj in loadedFile)
            {
                if (obj.functionName != null) 
                {
                    functionListBox.Items.Add(obj.functionName);
                    getParams(obj);   // I get exception here
                    funcParamList.Add(loadedFile);
                    functionListBox.Refresh();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: OpenFileDialog is your pick for the dialog. You will need to rewrite the file every time you change something.

Comment: Okay, I would work with that, I've already tried to do it with OpenFileDialog but couldn't make it. How should I do it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx scroll to the bottom, theres an example

Comment: This one didn't help me to get JSON objects. I've already checked it. (Edited my question with how I tried) Thank you.

Comment: you should write your json into .json files, thats how its normally done. I'm afraid I don't have the time to explain properly, maybe someone else can.

Comment: Also check out Path.Combine instead of using `@"<blablapath>\" + fileName + ".txt"`

Comment: Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by casting 'DeserializeObject' as List and it's done. Here the changes:

```
            ...

            var loadedFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FunctionData>>(jsonFile);
```